# Symfony2 ScopeCrossingInjectionException when you use prototype scope

Tags: service, symfony, scope

My aim is to add data_collector to my classes for displaying some useful information on the developer toolbar.
My service:

```
services:
    my_api.auth.login:
        class: YO\ApiV1\Services\Auth\Login
        arguments:
            - requestId
            - "@old_sound_rabbit_mq.login_rpc"
            - "@service_container"
        scope: prototype
```

I need scope prototype to have different instance for every new call. By the way, service @old_sound_rabbit_mq.login_rpc has scope "prototype" as well.
And, I'd like to attach data_collector, which could be done with:

```
tags:
    - { name: data_collector, template: "AcmeDebug:Collector:templatename", id: "your_collector_name" }
```

But then I got an exception:

> ScopeCrossingInjectionException: Scope Crossing Injection detected:
>   The definition "profiler" references the service "my_api.auth.login"
>   which belongs to another scope hierarchy. This service might not be
>   available consistently. Generally, it is safer to either move the
>   definition "profiler" to scope "prototype", or declare "container" as
>   a child scope of "prototype". If you can be sure that the other scope
>   is always active, you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid
>   of this error.

And it confuses me, because I don't know what to do. I tried to set property "strict=false", but nothing happens.

Comment: @mactpo have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

I guess symfony's synchronized services may help you: [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html)

otherwise you can set "strict=false" in this way:

```
services:
    my.service.definition:
        class: Acme\Services\BlaService
        arguments:
            - "@any_other_service_from_narrower_scope="
        scope: prototype
```

The "=" at the end of the service-definition when injecting a service from a narrower scope, will turn "strict" to false

Answer (score 1):

Container scope since Symfony 2.8 was deprecated.

`scope: prototype` was replaced by `shared: false`

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/service_container/shared.html